# Google speech to text

Tags: google-api, speech-to-text

I have having issue with google speech to text api

[https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_API}](https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=$%7BGOOGLE_CLOUD_API%7D)

I want to use a voice recording and make that into text with this. But I am not sure how to do this.

I tried with

```
mediaRecorder?.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
 console.log(event.data)
}
```

I can see the Blob {size: 21679, type: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus'} But I need to pass this to the axios post request

```
       const response = await axios.post(
            `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_API}`,
            {
                config: {
                    encoding: 'LINEAR16',
                    sampleRateHertz: 44100,
                    languageCode: 'en-US'
                },
                audio: {
                    content: window.btoa(event.data)
                }
            }
        )
```

I am getting result empty in the response transcript but I want results not empty